# Upload MP3 to Music Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions

I want to ask a question on the music stack exchange about my voice and I'd like to upload and MP3? Is this possible?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You'll have to host it somewhere. YouTube is your best option in my opinion, and some SE sites can even embed YouTube videos, though not sure about Music.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no support to upload files other than images (through Stack Exchange's own Imgur account). You can link the file though if you store it elsewhere. Maybe use an own online file storage service.

Make sure though not to breach copyright by making the file available for download. In some counties it might not be allowed to distribute it this way.